# Functional dependency: Two types determining third type

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

Why doesn't this code work:

```
class Foo a b c | a b -> c where
  foo :: a -> b -> c

instance Foo Int Int Int where
  foo a b = a + b  

ghci > foo 4 4  -- This produces run time error
```

And by using functional dependency, why the following code produces compile time error:

```
instance Foo Float Float Int where
  foo a b = a + b
```

I know that the above instance is an crazy example, but isn't the aim of functional dependency to help the type checker in resolving these issues ?

Comment: You forgot to include the text of the errors you are receiving in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it did resolve the ambiguity. The problem is that `4 :: Num a => a` so GHC can't decide that you want to use `foo :: Int -> Int -> Int`. Now if instead you did

```
foo (4 :: Int) (4 :: Int)
> 8
```

Since now it is clear which instance we want to use. To make this clearer, suppose we had

```
class Foo a b c | a -> b, a -> c where
  ...
```

Now we could do

```
foo (4 :: Int) 4
> 8
```

since once GHC has filled in all the type variables not on the right side of an `->`, it can fill in the rest.

Comment: Why you are having `a -> b` two times ?

Comment: There is no problem with declaring `instance Foo Float Float Int` so long as there are no other `instance Foo Float Float ...` around.  However that specific definition of `foo` won't type.

Answer (score 2):

```
instance Foo Float Float Int where
    foo a b = a + b
```

This is a error even without the functional dependency. If `a` and `b` are `Float`, then `a + b` is a `Float`, not an `Int`.